# How to remove workbook tabs and Column,row headers of spreadsheet using Custom UI Editor?

Tags: excel, vba

---

I am newbie in vba. I want to remove Ribbon, workbook tabs and ColumnRow headers in an excel. I could able to remove ribbon with this lines of code.

---

`<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
</ribbon>
</customUI>`

---

In the same way i want to remove the RowColumn headers of spreadsheets and workbook tabs of Excel. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not do everything you have requested but here is a starting point. Use the onLoad callback within the CustomUI xml code to run a macro that hides the headers:
XML File:

```
<customUI onLoad="uiLoad" xmlns="...">
```

VBA Macro:

```
Sub uiLoad()
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
End Sub
```